# How to download a file from private repo using c# octokit

Tags: c#, github, octokit.net

How to download a file from a private repo using c# octokit
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: did you try reading the documentation of octokit? Did you try writing any code solve this issue? What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For more information: [Octokit.net Documentation](https://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest)

```cs
        var gitHubClient = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("app-name"));
        var credentials = new Credentials(token: "your-token");
        gitHubClient.Credentials = credentials;

        var repositoryContents =
            await gitHubClient.Repository.Content.GetAllContents("owner", "repo-name");
        var firstOrDefault = repositoryContents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Path == @"path-of-the-file-you-want");
        var downloadUrl = firstOrDefault?.DownloadUrl;
```

Then you can download this file with the download url.